# Matching timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timestamp

I have two data frames with close timestamps.

```
DF1
Time                        A
2020-02-15 05:09:00         52
2020-02-15 05:19:00         12
2020-02-15 05:28:00         25
2020-02-15 05:49:00         36
```

second table

```
DF2      
Time                        B
2020-02-15 05:09:00         0.2
2020-02-15 05:19:00         0.25
2020-02-15 05:29:00         0.35
2020-02-15 05:39:00         0.45
2020-02-15 05:49:00         0.24
2020-02-15 05:59:00         0.32
```

I want to merge these two data frames based on the timestamp (closely, tolerance = 2 min ). The output should be look like

```
Time                  A    B  
2020-02-15 05:09:00   52   0.2
2020-02-15 05:19:00   12   0.25
2020-02-15 05:29:00   25   0.35
2020-02-15 05:39:00   NAN  0.45
2020-02-15 05:49:00   36   0.24
2020-02-15 05:59:00   NAN  0.32
```

I was trying to use

```
pd.merge_asof(DF2,DF1, on = "Time",allow_exact_matches=True)
```

Also

```
pd.merge_asof(DF2,DF1, on = "Time", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("120000ms"))
```

However, it dose not provide the output that I am trying to generate. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

From my end, the second code seems to work:

```
pd.merge_asof(df2,df1, on='Time', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2T'))
```

Output:

```
                 Time     B     A
0 2020-02-15 05:09:00  0.20  52.0
1 2020-02-15 05:19:00  0.25  12.0
2 2020-02-15 05:29:00  0.35  25.0
3 2020-02-15 05:39:00  0.45   NaN
4 2020-02-15 05:49:00  0.24  36.0
5 2020-02-15 05:59:00  0.32   NaN
```

If you like, you can chain with column arrangement to swap `A`, `B` columns:

```
pd.merge_asof(df2,df1, on='Time', 
               tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2T')
              )[['Time','A','B']]
```

Output:

```
                 Time     A     B
0 2020-02-15 05:09:00  52.0  0.20
1 2020-02-15 05:19:00  12.0  0.25
2 2020-02-15 05:29:00  25.0  0.35
3 2020-02-15 05:39:00   NaN  0.45
4 2020-02-15 05:49:00  36.0  0.24
5 2020-02-15 05:59:00   NaN  0.32
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this solution works for you, but i got your required answer.

In brief, the problem is that the pd.merge_asof works like left_join. So the retained values takes the index of the left dataframe used.

In this case, i tried using the DF2 as the left dataframe, then rearranged the column to retain the output result, and it worked.

```
combined = pd.merge_asof(DF2, DF1, on='Time', tolerance=pd.Timedelta("120000ms"))
new_cols = ['Time','A', 'B']
combined = combined[new_cols]
```

Got the output result

```
         Time            A       B
0   2020-02-15 05:09:00 52.0    0.20
1   2020-02-15 05:19:00 12.0    0.25
2   2020-02-15 05:29:00 25.0    0.35
3   2020-02-15 05:39:00 NaN     0.45
4   2020-02-15 05:49:00 36.0    0.24
5   2020-02-15 05:59:00 NaN     0.32
```